# Creating multiple instances(objects) of a class derived from a list of str

Tags: python, class

If I had a class and a list of names where I was asked to instantiate each name in the list as an object of the class, how would I do it?

```
class PlaceHolder():
    '''This class represents a place holder for this example'''

    pass

listofnames = ['Michael', 'Jay', 'Derrick']
for next_name in listofnames:
    next_name = PlaceHolder()
```

This does not work. I was wondering if there was a method to implement this?

Comment: You are trying to use dynamic variables. Don't do that... why don't you make `name` an *attribute of the class* then create a list of `PlaceHolder` objects? I.E `list_of_obs = [PlaceHolder(name=name) for name in listofnames]`

Comment: Your problem is more fundamental than instantiation: you're assigning to your loop index three times, throwing away the newly created object each time.  In short, you need to back up and learn to use loops and variables.  You need to learn to create a list from a loop and `append`.

Comment: Or, if you want to *access* them by name, use a `dict`, which you can index with a string, e.g. `dict_of_obs ={name:PlaceHolder(name=name) for name in listofnames}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and advice, you guys have similar ideas as the other people who proposed a solution which tells me it;s either impossible or it's a bad idea to do it how I want to...

Comment: @MichaelJohnson it is not impossible to use dynamic variables, it is just highly highly inadvisable in almost all situations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't work is that you are trying to initialize the class to a list item, which isn't going to do anything. The `for` loop `for next_name in listofnames` iterates through the values in `listofnames`.

Try,

```
listofnames = ['Michael', 'Jay', 'Derrick']
list_dict   = dict() 
for next_name in listofnames:
    list_dict[next_name] = PlaceHolder()
```

Where each list item has an assigned placeholder and is placed in the dictionary `list_dict`. It can be accessed by `list_dict[next_name]`

Comment: While your answer is reasonable, I think this sentence: "The reason it won't work is that you are trying to assign the class to a list item, which isn't possible" is... misleading.

Comment: This only maps the string name as the key and the placeholder object as a value right? As in there is no direct relationship between the string name and the class?

Comment: @MichaelJohnson I am unsure what you mean "direct relationship between the string name and the class" but this maps string keys to values that are objects of type `PlaceHolder`.

Comment: @MichaelJohnson there are ways to declare a variable directly and initialize it as a class, but using a dict is more robust and unlikely to create issues

Comment: Yeah, I meant if there was a relationship such that if I checked the type of Michael (e.g. (type(Michael())) would result with PlaceHolder()) it would return the class. So there's no way to manipulate the string name to become a object of the class?

Comment: this might help: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: @MichaelJohnson yes, there is, but you *shouldn't do that*.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed creating objects. The problem is you always store it in the same variable, so you overwrite it. Maybe you are looking something like this

```
class PlaceHolder():
    '''This class represents a place holder for this example'''

    pass

listofnames = ['Michael', 'Jay', 'Derrick']
instances = list()
for next_name in listofnames:
    instances.append(PlaceHolder())
print(instances)
```

Or a more pythonic way would be

```
instances = [PlaceHolder() for next_name in listofnames]
print(instances)
```

Comment: Interesting.. I'm guessing it's impossible to directly link the string text of the name to be instantiated into an object such that if I did type(Michael) == PlaceHolder()?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to set the variables the way you proposed, you can use the following:

```
for next_name in listofnames:
    exec("{} = Placeholder()".format(next_name))
```

I really wouldn't recommend this due to the dangers of using `exec`. Really, don't do this.

It'd be much better to keep these as keys in a dictionary.

```
my_objects = {}
for next_name in listofnames:
    my_objects[next_name] = Placeholder()

# And access via
my_objects['Michael'] # Placeholder instance
```

Comment: Ahaha ok.... I don't even know what the command 'exec' does... Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: `exec` will execute the given string as a line of code and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
class PlaceHolder():
    '''This class represents a place holder for this example'''

    pass

listofnames = ['Michael', 'Jay', 'Derrick']

for next_name in listofnames:
    globals()[next_name] = PlaceHolder() #create an instance of class PlaceHolder with name=next_name
    listofnames[listofnames.index(next_name)]=globals()[next_name] #replace the string in list with the class instance
```